# Can't access to class variable from other class

Tags: java

Good day! I have a class which read config.property file, i need access to class variables of this class from other.

Class which set value from property file to class variable "gateway":

```
    public class ReadPropertyFile {
    private String gateway;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadPropertyFile propCls = new ReadPropertyFile();
        propCls.setVlue();

    }

    public void setValue(){
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties")) {

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get the property value and print it out
        gateway = prop.getProperty("gateway");

    }

    public String getGateway() {
        return this.gateway;
    }
}
```

Class which return me value from ReadPropertyFile class:

**this method returns me null:**

```
public class getVariable{
    public static ReadPropertyFile propCls = new ReadPropertyFile();
    public static String gateway = propCls.getGateway();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(gateway);
    }
}
```

**this method returns me my property:**

```
public class getVariable{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadPropertyFile propCls = new ReadPropertyFile();
        propCls.setValue();
        String gateway= propCls.getGateway();   
        System.out.println(gateway);
    }
}
```

1. In first sample of getVariable method i tried to set value from property file to my class variable, it is my main question.
2. In second sample i created a class object in main class, then call setValue method and return my gateway property, without calling setValue method, class getVariable returns me null too.

Can someone explain how i need to rewrite my class from first sample to set value of ReadPropertyFile class to class variable getVariable class.

And why i need to calling setValue method from getVariable class to return me an a value of my gateway property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example does not work, because setValue method is not called from anywhere. In order to make your first example work, you have to add default constructor to your **ReadPropertyFile** class, where you call your method setValue().

```
public class ReadPropertyFile {
    private String gateway;

    public ReadPropertyFile() {
        setValue();

    }

    public void setValue(){
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties")) {

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get the property value and print it out
        gateway = prop.getProperty("gateway");

    }

    public String getGateway() {
        return this.gateway;
    }
}
```

Comment: is not calling of setValue method?     
`public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadPropertyFile propCls = new ReadPropertyFile();
        propCls.setVlue();

    }` or i just call the reference?

Comment: No, your main function is not called. Because you are running main function from other place. It is called only if you run your program inside ReadPropertyFile, but that is not what you need

Comment: Default constructor is what you need

Comment: Abzal, thank you a lot! It is what i need, i dont know about "Default constructor" before, you save my time!

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program with class getVariable as your main class, it will execute the main method of class getVariable, not the main method of class ReadPropertyFile.

One way to solve this would be to call setValue in a constructor of class ReadPropertyFile. Another way (better IMHO) would be to declare a static method in ReadPropertyFile that will create an instance, and invoke setValue.

Note that the fact that you're using verbs in you class names, is a smell that something is wrong in the design.